# How does sqlcounter/data limit in Freeradius 3 work?

Tags: freeradius

Have my captive portal environment setup using pfSense 2.3.4 with Freeradius 3.0.13 hosted on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with Rasparian Jessie. Authentication and everything is working as expected but can't get the sql counter for volume limit to work.

According to the documentation there are only examples how to set a max session time, daily usage (in time) but nothing for limiting the volume.

Have added this custom function in the sqlcounter file:

```
sqlcounter totalbytecounter {
  sql_module_instance = sql
  dialect = mysql

  counter_name = Max-Volume
  check_name = Acct-Output-Octets
  reply_name = Session-Timeout

  key = User-Name
  reset = never
  query = "SELECT ((SUM(`acctinputoctets`)+SUM(`acctoutputoctets`))) FROM radacct WHERE `username`='%{${key}}'"
}
```

But debug says

```
(34) totalbytecounter: WARNING: Couldn't find check attribute, control:Acct-Output-Octets, doing nothing...
```

Anyone that can help me in the right direction`? Thanks!

Comment: Have you managed to fix this issue? I'm looking for the same solution, and I'm surprised that there are counters for time, but not for data usage.  I can't find a single working solution that explains this well enough.

Comment: Yes, I did solve it, not on a user level but I'm able to control data volume per usergroup. The attribute named "Max-Daily-Volume" should go in the "radgroupcheck"-table. I don't have access to the freeradius config right now but can get back to you as soon as I've checked.

Comment: It would be great, if you could show me that, if you have access. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a value for `control:Acct-Output-Octets` for the module to check against.

That can be in unlang with

```
update control {
    Acct-Output-Octets := 1024
}
```

or in the users file with

```
<username> Acct-Output-Octets := 1024
```

or as an entry in the radcheck table.

Comment: I added a row `(NULL, 'fredm', 'Acct-Output-Octets', '=', '1000000')` in the radcheck table, the problem is I always get "access-rejected" when trying to login

Comment: The "update control", in which file do I need to add that? I have tried the `Max-Daily-Session` counter and that seems to work fine, I'm kicked out after the 900 seconds have passed. In the radacct table there is a "Session-Timeout" like it should. But can't get the same to work with the total bytes counter.

Comment: update control goes in the authorize section of your virtual server.  Default is raddb/sites-available/default.

Comment: Could you post the output of radiusd -X to pastebin or equivalent?

Comment: Will post output. Meanwhile, can someone please post sample code what to put in the authorize section? It seems the sql query will return 1 or 0 rows and that what makes the statement true or false, but I'm not sure about that?